# Create custom definition for chain rule of partial derivative of a vector-valued function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

I'm trying to calculate derivatives of expressions involving an unknown function $F: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, with respect to a parameter $h \in \mathbb{R}$.

As an example, with symbolic tensor definitions

```
$Assumptions=M \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]] &&
 q \[Element] Vectors[d, Reals] &&
 v \[Element] Vectors[d, Reals]
```

and the following expression, I get

```
expr=M.q + h M.v + F[h + t, q + h v, M.v];
(* Input: *) D[expr, h]
(* Output: *) M . v + v*Derivative[0, 1, 0][F][h + t, q + h*v, M . v] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][F][h + t, q + h*v, M . v]
```

which is *almost* what I want, except that in the second term `v` should not be multiplied with the derivative of `F` using `Times`, but using `Dot`, taking into account that `F` is a vector-valued function. That is, the chain rule should be applied with the assumption that `v` is a vector.

I know that custom rules for derivatives to be used by `D` can be defined as e.g.

```
Derivative[1, 0][function][x_, y_] := y;
```

but this form presupposes that the derivative is taken with respect to the arguments of the function, whereas in my case I want to differentiate with respect to $h$, which is not an argument of $F$ in its original form, while its arguments can depend on it. In other words, in this application, $F$ appears as a part of an expression that depends on $h$, and I would like to differentiate this expression while taking into account the symbolic tensor definitions.

Any idea on how to achieve the desired outcome?

*Note: The above `expr` is just a simple example, of course, I need to calculate first- and higher-order derivatives of much more complex symbolic expressions with respect to $h$.*

Comment: This sort of question has been asked before, and I think some answers present workarounds suitable for the OP's uses. I can't seem to find any right now (sorry). I think sometimes it is done by picking an explicit dimension `d`. Another difficulty, I believe, is that `Derivative[0,..,0, 1, 0,...,0][f]` denotes the ***partial*** derivative ("effectively" `D[f[..., #,...], #] &` per the documentation). It is not designed to represent the derivative matrix (Jacobian). I am sure that neither `Derivative` nor `D` pay any attention to `$Assumptions`.

Comment: I've implemented this kind of thing dozens of times and my advice is to write a minimal DSL specifying how your tensor derivatives operate using some kind of generalized `Dot` function (i.e. just call it `tDot`). This will allow you to specify everything with respect to stuff that shows up in real world libraries, like `np.tensordot` or via a `Transpose` + `ArrayReshape` + `Dot` combo in Mathematica. Once you implement this once, you'll find yourself doing it over and over again since it's *maybe* 6 definitions to get it going

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am open to this approach, but with my lack of experience, some examples would be welcome, if any are available.